# Passing methods to all elements of a set containing object pointers, C++

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, set

I've got a class derived from a set containing pointers to another class' objects.
Basically it looks like this:

```
class connectionSLOT: private std::set<connectionSLOT*>
{
...
};
```

It's very simple and works fine to represent (directed) graphs, perhaps. My class also contains some simple methods like connect(), disconnect(), and so on, all of them expect object pointers as argument and also return with such a pointers.
(i.e. their declarations differ only in their names)
For instance:

```
connectionSLOT* connectionSLOT::connect(connectionSLOT *A)
{
  insert (A); return A;
}
```

Or:

```
connectionSLOT* connectionSLOT::disconnect(connectionSLOT *A)
{
  erase(A); return this;
}
```

So, my issue is: how can I make a new method which applied these functions not on the object itself but all the objects contained in the set (ie contained in the calling object) ?

I  would like to have something like this:

```
connectionSLOT* new_method( 'passing a method (and its argument) ' )
{
  for(it=begin();it!=end();++it) 'execute the method on (*it)' ;
  return something;
}
```

It would be applied for connecting all the neighbor points to a certain vertex, perhaps.
But because new_method() itself is also a proper function it could be passed too:

```
int main()
{
  // ... here declaring some objects and connection amongst them...

  A->new_method( new_method( disconnect(B) ) ) ;

/* calling new_method() recursively to disconnect all the vertices from B which ones are
    reachable from A in two steps */

...
}
```

I hope, it's possible to do somehow. (syntax is basically not important)
Giving any suggestion is appreciated.

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use C++11? I believe, that `std::function` and lambda expressions are what you are searching for.

```
void DoSth(std::function<void(void)> fn)
{
    fn();
}

DoSth([]() { printf("Hello, world!\n"); });
```

Your code would look more-less like the following:

```
connectionSLOT::new_method(std::function<void(connectionSlot *)> fn)
{
    for (it = begin(); it != end(); ++it)
        fn(*it);

    return something;
} 

int main()
{
    // ... here declaring some objects and connection amongst them...

    A->new_method([](connectionSlot * B) { disconnect(B); } );

    // ...
}
```

Comment: wow! Thank you for the fast answer! Yes, I use that version (with gnu C++ compiler) and your solution is exactly that I need! :) Thank you so much!